# Rocket league does not show frame rate when using a steam controller on PC

Tags: steam, rocket-league, framerate, controllers

Title says it all, I have my steam settings set up to display FPS in the top left which works on rocket league when using keyboard and mouse, and Dota 2 (also when using keyboard and mouse) curiously enough when rocket league is started while using the steam controller fps does not appear in the designated spot.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably in Big Picture mode, which does not have an FPS counter, even if it's on in the main/non Big Picture mode. If you use a Steam Controller or an Xbox/PS4/other controller with Configuration Support enabled and it's connected, the overlay will be in Big Picture mode, even without you turning it on in the Steam client.